# how do i fix debugpy syntax error when using py2exe to convert a py file to and exe?

Tags: python, syntax-error, py2exe

I am trying to convert a py file to an exe file but there seems to be a few syntax errors inside debugpy. I want to use the exe file to edit word documents and as i understood pyinstaller for example dont work with that. So im trying to use py2exe.

From what i can see inside the file, there seems to be multiple syntax errors and i tried to fix them manually but that didnt seems to work either.

Is there something wrong with debugpy itself or is it any other programs that clashes with it?

Its also starts with an exception:
Start:

```
C:\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py:258: VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
    Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.

  return self._find_and_load(name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 671, in __code__
    self.__code_object__ = compile(source, __file__, "exec",
  File "_pydev_imps\_pydev_pkgutil_old.pyc", line 543
    except IOError, msg:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Falling back to loader to get code for module _pydev_imps._pydev_pkgutil_old
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 675, in __code__
    raise RuntimeError("compiling %r" % self) from None
RuntimeError: compiling Module(_pydev_imps._pydev_pkgutil_old, 'C:\\Python_3.9\\lib\\site-packages\\debugpy\\_vendored\\pydevd\\_pydev_imps\\_pydev_pkgutil_old.py')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Programs\Word_Document_Creator\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Python_3.9\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python_3.9\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
```

End:

```
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 923, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python_3.9\lib\site-packages\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_pkgutil_old.py", line 543
    except IOError, msg:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That's Python 2 code, it's not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.